# ColorBox close button refreshing parent window on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

This is the code which is being used to display overlay using Jquery colorbox plugin

```
function inlineLightbox(h) {
    jQuery.colorbox({
        opacity: 0.6,
        inline: true,
        href: h,
        onOpen: function() {
            jQuery('#colorbox').addClass('inline');
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            jQuery('#colorbox a.close, #colorbox a.btn-close').click(function() {
                jQuery.colorbox.close();
                jQuery('#product-popup-help').removeClass('active'); jQuery('#product-editors-notes').addClass('active');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is how i am calling this

```
inlineSigninLightbox('#popup-password-update-confirm');
```

where the overlay which will b shown in the color-box is in a div.My problem is when i am closing the colorbox my parent window is getting refreshed which i don't want

i am not sure why this is happening

Comment: how do you call `inlineLightbox` by `inlineSigninLightbox()`?

Comment: @undefined: i am calling it based on some condition

Answer (score 1):

That code looks fine to me.  I believe your problem is being caused by something that was not included in your post.

Have you checked your JavaScript console for errors?

Are you absolutely sure that your selector ('#colorbox a.close, #colorbox a.btn-close') is matching the link elements you are clicking on?

Answer (score 0):

first thing your are defining inlineLightbox() function 
and you are calling somthing else function inlineSigninLightbox('#popup-password-update-confirm');

and to prevent from reload or other event bubbling after clicking close button you can use this

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: my mistake, both functions are same excpet the one i am calling is for signup process which use some predefined variables.i checked its having same issue in othe rone